# Hive: using quote character as delimiter in data files

Tags: hive, hql, bigdata

Can we use quote (" or ') as delimiter in hive data files? If not why?
If we could refer to a list of characters which we can use as delimiters for hive data, that would be great.

Comment: Why would you like to do somtehing like this?

Comment: @ Dudu: In our data, we have all sort of character combinations that can be used as delimiter like "\t", pipe (|) etc. So we were wondering what we can use for delimiter and found out that quotation does not appear in our data.

Comment: This sounds like a bad choice. How bout the default Hive delimiter `SOH` (decimal value `1`), or any other control character for that matter?

Answer (score 0):

When using the decimal notation, you can use the whole basic ascii range (decimal 0-127) - **tested**.
Avoid using `\n` or`\r`.

As for `"` and `'`, it can be done straightforward -

```
create table mytable (i int,j int) row format delimited fields terminated by '"';
create table mytable (i int,j int) row format delimited fields terminated by "'";
```

or

```
create table mytable (i int,j int) row format delimited fields terminated by '\'';
create table mytable (i int,j int) row format delimited fields terminated by "\"";
```